# Login with Google Profiles identifier no longer working, new sites do not associate automatically

Tags: support, status-completed, openid, google-openid

Google made a change to profiles, and now I don't seem to be able to log in using the old identifier (www.google.com/profiles/USERNAME) or the new URL (profiles.google.com/USERNAME).

Is it safe to just use the http://www.google.com/accounts/08/id identifier without changing the URL in all my SE accounts? I logged in using that identifier and it did appear to log me in after asking for my email address.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Use the OpenID selector to choose the "Google_Profile" provider
2. Enter a Google username with a Google Profile (mine, for example)
3. Receive the error message:

   > Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
   >   No OpenID endpoint found.

Comment: I can confirm the same

Comment: The problem I just had is that I tried to log in using "google.com/profiles/name", but that's redirecting to "profiles.google.com/name". It's working for OpenID, but not recognizing my StackExchange account with the new URL.

Comment: you should ask your addendum as another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the Google Profile OpenID changed from

`https://www.google.com/profiles/example`

to

`https://profiles.google.com/example`

So, I did a global network replace on

```
Regex.Replace(OpenId, 
    'https?://www\.google\.com/profiles/(.*)', 
    'https://profiles.google.com/$1')
```

For both OpenId fields.

I also updated the login form to use the correct, updated URL.

This should correct the problem.