# Account associations gone funny with Google Profile OpenId change

Tags: support, status-completed, openid, google-openid

Bear with me...

1. I went to sign into mechanics pre-beta, but couldn't because it couldn't associate the new url of Google Profile OpenId (profiles.google.com), with the 'old' one on Area51 (www.google.com/profiles)
2. So I switched/updated my OpenId on Area51, and managed to sign in to mechanics - but the system could only automatically associate me with Area51.
3. That seemed pretty normal to me - they both use the new url.
4. However, now on all the other sites where I have accounts, I *only* see Area51 and mechanics under accounts.

I can fiddle all of this manually, but I figured it might be useful for devs to have something to look at, if there's anything that needs fixing.

Quick links:
[Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/334?tab=accounts#tab-top), [mechanics](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/142/benjol?tab=accounts), [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11410/benjol?tab=accounts), [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130064/benjol?tab=accounts), [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/2238/benjol?tab=accounts), [SU](https://superuser.com/users/2962/benjol?tab=accounts), [SF](https://serverfault.com/users/1772/benjol?tab=accounts), [photo](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1812/benjol?tab=accounts), [english](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/529/benjol?tab=accounts), [atheism](http://atheism.stackexchange.com/users/756/benjol?tab=accounts), [cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/3680/benjol?tab=accounts), [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/4285/benjol?tab=accounts), [apps](https://stackapps.com/users/876/benjol?tab=accounts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see

[Login with Google Profiles identifier no longer working, new sites do not associate automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82118/login-with-google-profiles-identifier-no-longer-working-new-sites-do-not-associa)

But, you may need to clear associations and re-associate to re-match the changed sites.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll have a look. Edit: It worked!